# How to trouble shooting docker container killed with error code 137

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container started by docker-compose, it kills itself every time, using `docker logs` I can see things like:

```
ework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2018-05-19 12:01:44.920  INFO 5 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-05-19 12:01:46.022  INFO 5 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.3.8.Final
2018-05-19 12:01:46.073  INFO 5 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final
2018-05-19 12:01:46.196  WARN 5 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2018-05-19 12:01:46.200  WARN 5 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2018-05-19 12:01:46.259  INFO 5 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-19 12:01:46.260  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5446 ms
2018-05-19 12:01:47.394  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'org.smarter.configuration.JerseyConfiguration' to [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.407  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.418  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.422  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.424  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.424  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.424  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.424  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-19 12:01:47.425  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
Killed
```

The last line 'killed' shows that the container was killed by something, using `docker inspect`, I can see the exit code is 137, but OOMKilled is false.

I guess it was killed because of resource limitation configuration, how can I view the configuration? and how can I remove the constraints if there is any?

Comment: Likely killed by the kernel, rather than docker itself. Check the OS logs.

Comment: Based on [this article](https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137), the application could be consuming too much memory. Java applications such as yours may need modified `-Xmx` and `-Xms` settings.